# Dreamweaver-like "related files" viewer and editor for Sublime Text 3

Tags: dreamweaver, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Not sure if this has been answered already as I could not find anything. 
I was using Dreamweaver for the longest time but switched almost immediately to Sublime last year.

The problem is I have gotten very used to viewing and editing the related CSS & JS files linked or referenced from the parent HTML file in DW-CS6.

Is there any functionality or plugin for Sublime that enables this accessibility? - See screenshot for what I'm specifically talking about.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, no, but I could be wrong. Instead, use "Go to anything" - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

The thought is if you are building something, you have set up a project, which adds all the files that are a part of the thing you are building. Alternatively, you can drag & drop said folder from your computer into ST3 - this is like a de facto project.

Once done, instead of clicking `style.css` and searching for `myCoolClass`, you can just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and start typing. without knowing your file, I am betting you'd only have to type `myc` or `myco` before it is found. You can just review the part of the file - or pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> will open `style.css`. Now you don't need to remember that myCoolClass is in `style.css` vs `style-desktop.css`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RyanB, dragging the folder to ST3 does somewhat address the problem, but still lacks basic real-time connectivity that DWCS6 has in terms of the related files and edits made on-the-fly.